# How to control group breaks in ReportBuilder?

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

In Delphi, using Digital Metaphors' Report Builder, I'm creating a report that is grouped by a field (named "Section").

I would like the groups to be printed one after the other without breaks, unless another field (named "SectionType") has a certain value, in which case, the group must start on a new page.

I have tried to use the `onGetBreakValue` event with no success.

How can I achieve the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 groups on your report, first by "Section" then by "SectionType" under the Report -> Groups... (Ctrl+G) menu option in the report designer. There you can select the Start New Page for the "SectionType".

Comment: OP also said if 'SectionType' has a certain value.. I imagine some code is required to check for OP's particular SectionType...